# java connection problem with mysql

Tags: java, servlets

I want to connect my java web application with the mysql database but whenever I am running the program it is throwing the following error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:959)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1430)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:21)
        at UserDAO.login(UserDAO.java:29)
        at LoginServlet.doGet(LoginServlet.java:27)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:734)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clear that driver class is not in your class path

[add this jar in your classpath](http://www.findjar.com/class/com/mysql/jdbc/Driver.html)

Here is how to add jar in classpath in Netbeans:

```
Select your Project -> Right Click -> Properties -> Libraries -> add jar -> select jar -> ok
```

Comment: but can you please tell me how to add the jar file in the class path coz i am absolutely new in this java systems

Comment: @Abhisek sure, You are using any IDE like netbeans/eclipse? or using text editor to write code ? how do you run it /

Answer (score 5):

seems as though the mysql driver jar is not on the classpath.
Have you confirmed you have installed the mysql jdbc jar file and it is referenced on the classpath?
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html

Comment: This is a quite old driver, I'd update the link to reflect the most recent one.

Comment: no i have set it in the classpath  but still it is creating problem .... previously it was working but now throwing this exception